# display a random string in a button in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, button, random, output

I have the following code to display a random string from my array on a button, but I can't figure out what's wrong (the declared array isn't included below). There is definitely a problem with the last line. Thanks!

```
             int index = [self.colorlist count];
             int random = (arc4random() % index);
             NSString *color1 = [self.colorlist objectAtIndex:random];
             [Button1 setTitle:@"%@", color1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

[`setTitle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSButton/setTitle%3a) accepts an `NSString`, not a [format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat%3a) (`@"%@", color1`):

```
[Button1 setTitle:color1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```